# Breakpoint in Pycharm when called from xlwings

Tags: python, excel, pycharm, anaconda, xlwings

I can't get the breakpoint to work when I call python code from xlwings.

testme.py:

```
import xlwings as xw

def add(n):
    result = []
    while len(result) < n:
        result.append(1+4)
    return result

def xl_add():
    sht = xw.Book.caller().sheets[0]           
    n = sht.range('B1').options(numbers=int).value
    seq = add(n)
    sht.range('C1').expand('vertical').clear_contents()
    sht.range('C1').options(transpose=True).value = seq

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xw.serve()
```

I saved an XL sheet in the same directory with this VBA code:

```
Sub CallTestMe()
    RunPython ("import testme; testme.xl_add()")
End Sub
```

in xlwings.bas I change the settings to:

```
PYTHON_WIN = "D:\Anaconda3\python.exe"
UDF_DEBUG_SERVER = True
```

I then started pycharm and set a breakpoint inside of add(n), and started the debugger.

```
D:\Anaconda3\python.exe "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 18601 --file D:/sletmig/xlwings/testme.py
pydev debugger: process 8684 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 171.4694.38)
xlwings server running, clsid={506E67C3-55B5-48C3-A035-EED5DEEA7D6D}
```

I call the VBA code and it returns a row of 5s in column C **but no breakpoint was hit**. In cell B1 I have a number 10.

Versions of software
Pycharm Community Edition 2017.4
xlwings v0.10.4
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (32-bit)
Office 2013 32 bit
Windows 10, 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to set breakpoints in UDF functions like these:

```
@xw.func
def double_sum(x, y):
    """Returns twice the sum of the two arguments"""
    return 2 * (x + y)                   

def main():
    # To run this with the debug server, set UDF_DEBUG_SERVER = True in the xlwings VBA module
    xw.serve()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The breakpoint is when you start the server in Pycharm and call it from XL =DOUBLE_SUM(1,2)